# PHP copy() problems and special characters

Tags: php, regex, filesystems

I'm currently copying certain files when the user updates certain information. However, since we cannot have any special any special characters when specifically naming windows files, is there a regex that exists to do specifically that? All the special characters found will be replaced by an underscore to keep matters simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is use "slugifier" like [Slugify](https://github.com/cocur/slugify) this will be more secure and tested than a regexp because will work with all encodings and strange chars.

A little example ussing Slugify

```
use Cocur\Slugify\Slugify;

$slugify = new Slugify();//for iconv translit
echo $slugify->slugify('Hello World!'); // hello-world
```

Another lib is [urlify](https://github.com/jbroadway/urlify) a PHP port of URLify.js from the Django project:

```
echo URLify::filter ('фото.jpg', 60, "", true);
// "foto.jpg"
```

Is pretty easy to use and maybe the best solution.

Or maybe you can use this spare class:
https://github.com/mongator/behaviors/blob/master/src/Mongator/Behavior/Util/SluggableUtil.php

Regards

Comment: I tried running this but I'm getting issues with: ***static::seemsUtf8** method.

Comment: Which problem you have? I have this running in my project. Is better use Slugify you can install it with composer instead of copy the code.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the special characters you want to replace, but to for example replace all non-word character and the `-` sign, you could use:

```
$new_value = preg_replace("/[^-\w]+/", "_", $original_value);
```

This will leave only `-`, `_`, `a-z` (also upper case) and `0-9` and replace the rest with underscores.

Comment: In this case, it would be replacing any special characters that is not  valid for a windows file name.

Comment: @Dimitri I don't know what characters are included exactly, but just add what you want to preserve to the character class (note that it is a negated character class). A white-list is always better than a black-list.